# Single dependency management for monorepo

Tags: npm, lerna, monorepo

I am working on a **monorepo** using `lerna`. I have a main package, my application (`app`), which is a `react` application and a couple of other packages, which often times are `react` components.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CollectionBrowser from '@elmc/app-collection-browser';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header>...</header>
        <CollectionBrowser />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here I am importing `CollectionBrowser` which exports a `react` component:

**CollectionBrowser.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class CollectionBrowser extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>foobar</div>;
    }
}
```

Now there are 2 things that bug me:

1. I am importing and bundling `react` twice, one time in my main app and another time, independent of that, in my CollectionBrowser. Is there a nice way to bundle `react` only once?
2. I have 2 (or any number of) build scripts, one for each package that I create. Isn't there a nice way to have one bundler and one transpile process?

Answer (score 0):

You could have react as a **peer** dependency on each package which uses it. This way any one of your projects based on react can chose its version and you can add only the packages you need.

Or the second approach would be to have a ui-core package in your library This ui-core can then have react as a dependency and it could be required by all your other packages which use react.

Concerning 2, we build and release everything on a per package basis.